# Controls in iOS for quiz app with differing number of answers to questions

Tags: ios

I'm working on a quiz app.

The thing I've noticed is that my questions may not always have a fixed number of answers. Instead of say, 4 possible answers and 1 correct answer, I could have 6 possible answers with 2 correct answers.

Is there a way to deal with this?

What I don't want to do is have buttons not in use.

At the moment I'm wondering if there is a way of having multiple view controllers depending on how many possible answers there are, or to have the buttons become inactive if there is no answer to be selected?

Comment: What about combobox like control ?  Imagine a survey like application where you have multiple possible options.

Comment: I'll check it out. I was trying to avoid asking questions until I'd finished the course on Udemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fully possible. You should use a TableView / CollectionView to achieve that.

You will be able to change the number of items, according to your answers count, and allow user to select from 0 to N answers.

Moreover, it it is reusable components, so you will have to design your UI for 1 question, and all the following will reuse the same layout

Comment: @bobby You should't ask users to upvote or accept answers.  People should vote as they see fit.